# TikZ append does not overwrite – what does?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

#### Main Question

I want to change all properties of certain TikZ elements in the style of TikZ’ `append`.
However, unlike its name suggests, `append` provides only defaults.
By contrast, I wish to override any detailed settings made in the specific TiKZ commands.
Is there any general way to do this?

I noticed that the handle `every axis plot post` in PGF Plots does something similar, but I lack the knowledge to translate its source to my problem.

#### Example

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{every path/.append style={dashed,draw=red}}
    \draw[dotted]        (0,0) -- (1,1);
    \draw[dotted,dashed] (0,1) -- (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of example code]

Here, the `dotted` argument of the `\draw` command superseeds the general style `dashed` by append. Only literally appending the `dashed` property (second line) works.

I am looking for something to write at the beginning of the `tikzpicture` looking like:

```
\tikzset{every path/.override style={dashed}}
```

and causing all lines in the above to be dashed. For me it would suffice to explicitly override the `dotted` property here.

#### Actual Application

I have a plot file generated with `tikzplotlib` (using `add_axis_environment=False`) featuring dashed lines and I want to change the dash pattern without manually changing the file. I know I could programmatically modify the plot file, but then my format specifications would not be bundled in one place (my TEX file) any more.

Comment: Append appends to `every path`, i.e. to the defaults of that key. But the every path key is executed before any of the settings for a single path apply (this is a usual pattern to allow local overrides for global configs). So you are setting the wrong key…

Comment: Do you know in advance which effects you want to nullify?

Comment: @TeXnician: *Do you know in advance which effects you want to nullify?* – Yes, see the last section.

Comment: Well, it was more a question which effect you want to nullify in the sense of "is it a specific set of keys or may it be arbitrary"? In the first case one could locally undeclare these keys. If it's the last one we'll have to wait for a TikZpert.

Comment: @TeXnician: I am not fully sure I got you right, but please see my edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to "nullify" the effect of a style, you can redefine it:

```
\tikzset{dotted/.style={dashed}
```